# ASP.NET all hidden field values lost on postback

Tags: asp.net

I am using AntiCSRF Library and in very small number of cases I got exception "CSRF form field is missing" - in fact all hidden fields (including "standard" ASP.NET) are lost on postback - example log entry:

> POST
>   http://xxx.pl:81/Delegations/DelegationEdit.aspx?id=null&source=~/Delegations/Delegations.aspx&search=&page=1&all=False&filters=-5;-1;2;2013-07-18;2013-10-18;;;;&view=1&tab=0&sort=date_from+desc
>   HTTP/1.1 
> Cache-Control: no-cache
> Connection: Keep-Alive
>   Content-Length: 65306
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data;
>   boundary=---------------------------7dd2343b20406
> Accept: text/html,
>   application/xhtml+xml, */* Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>   Accept-Language: pl-PL
> Cookie:
>   loginData=userName=jks&system=AVK&language=pl; ASP.NET_SessionId=xxx;
>   happilyLoggedIn=; .ASPXAUTHWB20=xxx;
>   __CSRFCOOKIE=428dcc73-f57a-449a-a6c7-d50cc50a9a53
> Host: xxx.pl
> Referer: https://xxx.pl/Delegations/DelegationEdit.aspx?id=null&source=%7e%2fDelegations%2fDelegations.aspx&search=&page=1&all=False&filters=-5%3b-1%3b2%3b2013-07-18%3b2013-10-18%3b%3b%3b%3b&view=1&tab=0&sort=date_from+desc
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64;
>   Trident/5.0)
> X-SSL-cipher: AES128-SHA              SSLv3 Kx=RSA   Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
> X-Forwarded-For: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

Page is pretty complex (lots of controls - big ViewState /which is chunked - maxPageStateFieldLength="30720"/, UpdatePanels, ASP.NET Web services usage). Problem mainly occurs on IEs (8, 9) and on one specific page.
I cannot reproduce this problem locally.
All ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Issues might be caused by [Pound front-end](http://www.apsis.ch/pound). Tried higher logging level and Client configuration options without luck. There are no way to disable sanitization. Currently switched to nginx - will see if it will help.